# Why does RSpec fail on that validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have these validations :

```
it "should have 100 adventure points" do
    user = User.new
    user.adventure_points.should == 100
end 

it "should be level 1" do
    user = User.new
    user.level.should == 1
end

it "should have 10 sapphires" do
    user = User.new
    user.sapphires.should == 10 
end
```

Then, i also have in my migration :

```
  t.string :name,                          :limit => 20
  t.integer :strength_points,              :default => 0
  t.integer :dexterity_points,             :default => 0
  t.integer :magic_points,                 :default => 0
  t.integer :accuracy_points,              :default => 0
  t.integer :health_points,                :default => 0
  t.integer :level,                        :default => 1
  t.integer :adventure_points,             :default => 100
  t.integer :sapphires,                    :default => 10
  t.integer :duel_wins,                    :default => 0
  t.integer :duel_losses,                  :default => 0      
  t.string  :image_url       
  t.integer :strength
```

When i run rspec i get :

```
A new User
  is not valid without a name
  is not valid without a first class
  is not valid without a password
  should have 100 adventure points
  should be level 1 (FAILED - 1)
  should have 10 sapphires (FAILED - 2)

Failures:

  1) A new User should be level 1
     Failure/Error: user.level.should == 1
       expected: 1
            got: nil (using ==)
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:28

  2) A new User should have 10 sapphires
     Failure/Error: user.sapphires.should == 10
       expected: 10
            got: nil (using ==)
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:33
```

Why does it present these errors on level, sapphires, but it works ok for adventure_points ? Moreover, if i open a console and do User.new, i get the default values as expected. What is hapening here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself, pretty sneaky one. I had to run rake:test:prepare because the test database did not have fixtures data and was not prepared :P

Answer (score 1):

The database defaults are not set until the model is saved. Try:

```
it "should have 100 adventure points" do
    user = User.create
    user.adventure_points.should == 100
end
```

Comment: i thought of that, but it does not work. You see adventure_points works well although it's set with User.new